# DosuSign connect not working for any event and not sending any response

Tags: c#, xml, implementation, docusignapi

I have setup a webhook on docuSign website to capture the response of the request. I have checked all the events (Sent, delivered, signed,completed etc.)  but none of the event is hitting the controller method I define in URL. The request object is coming back as null. All I am doing for now is getting the response and saving to local drive. Here is the sample code.

```
        public void GetDocumentResponse(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {            
        var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        var result = request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        xmldoc.Load(result);  
        }
```

Webhook name is mysite/Home/GetDocumentResponse.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to C# and docuSign, so please include the details in your response. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You  are probably getting an error from the server.  Use a sniffer like Wireshark or fiddler that you can done load for free and check response status which should be a 200 done for a good message.  The website probably is sending http 1.1 chunk mode so you will need to put into your request httl 1.0 :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("url");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: Also check and share the logs in the DS Admin console. Logs will show what error DS is receiving on sending Connect message to your listener. And the listener should accept a POST message and your controller should accept an XML format message.

Comment: Where should I look for logs.

Comment: You need to go to Connect in the "Go To Admin", on Connect screen, you will see two buttons `Logs` and `Failures`. If its successfully posted then the XML message will be in `Logs` else it will be in `Failures` with error details.

Comment: Also I hope you are deploying your listener on a public Ip not localhost as messages cannot be posted to localhost

Comment: I still have issues with DocuSign and I have already tried so many things. Not sure what is missing. Do you have any working example of DocuSign which I can refer. Thank you.